# Correct way to design the REST api

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, solid-principles

I have created REST apis to manage a resource (with endpoint say  `/user/resource` ). I can query the resource making a GET call and create the resource using the POST call. I use the api to manage resources from UI by making ajax calls to the REST api endpoint.

Now there is a requirement to send an email upon creating resource, and if the resource is already existing then sending a mail with the resource details in the mail (without modifying the resource) . I am confused if sending mail should be part of the the original REST api used for creating the resource or sending the mail should be handled separately . If "sending the mail" isn't part of the original REST api then it would involve some more handling on my UI for making another call to send a mail. Also if i expose "sending the mail" logic by means of another REST api then how should the endpoint be structured , will it be something like `/user/resource/email` since the mail sending is only related to the resource or should it be `/user/email`

Comment: is this the same for non-api application? if so, you should do that logic in model and in your api view you should call methods from model. If not, just write a method for sending emails in a view and call it from create or update  methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. However, you can try to send mail in same api where you are performing business operation.

For example:

```
public Object createResource() {
     //Perform your business operation here
     //check if your resource is already exists or not. Depending on the result call
    Object sendEail(..,..,..);
}

private Object sendEail(String address,String subject,String body) {
    //Write code for sending mail here
}
```

I hope you understand my point.